# Are the force frequencies the same in the discrete and continuous case?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, collision

Let's say I have an ideal gas of particles and the strike zone of area $\sigma=\pi d^2$ of a molecule of the molecule is what is the sub system considered. The end of the face of the cylinder is the strike zone. One may visualize it via 2 methods:

The continuum method:

[image]

Or the discrete method:

[image]

**1. Continuum Mechanics**

Resorting to continuum mechanics, then the fluid element (of a molecule) which will strike the target once every $\tau_F$ (the mean free time) on average. The magnitude of the force applied will be $P|\sigma|$.
Intuitively, this makes sense as then the gas will have an internal pressure of $P$ (with each collision) and one will have a force frequency of $\bar F_{\nu}$

$$ \bar F_{\nu} = \frac{P |\sigma|}{\tau_F}  $$

Note: $$\lim_{\tau_F \to 0}\bar F_{\nu} \tau_F = P |\sigma|$$ Does indeed give the correct equation  $$|F| = P|\sigma|$$

Where $P$ is pressure and $\sigma$ is the area of a molecule.

**2. Discrete Mechanics**

Now, if I remain in the discrete case I have the gas exerting a force $F_C$ (which is [renormalizable](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105668/150174)) during the interval of the collision $\tau_C$ a collision interval. In this case the force frequency is $\bar F_{\nu}' $

$$\bar F_{\nu}' =  \frac{\langle |F_C| \rangle}{\tau_C} $$

Since both models are describing the same system, I was wondering if there prove/disprove this conjecture:

$$ \frac{P |\sigma|}{\tau_F} \approx \frac{\langle |F_C| \rangle}{\tau_C}$$

Comment: What exactly is your $F_C$ here? Is it the force per molecule or the total force from the gas?

Comment: Force experienced by the face of the molecule on the time average in the interval $\tau_c$

Comment: How exactly is the function $\bar{F}_{\nu}$ written, since the limit problems come down to integral equations? $\nu-->0$ or $\tau_{F}$

Comment: So the force frequency is defined by (time averaged force)/(time interval of force applied)

Comment: @MoreAnonymous The wording of this question is very confusing. (1) What do you mean by "face of the molecule"? Molecules do not have faces, they are not cuboids. (2) Is the system you are considering simply an ideal gas of molecules? (3) What is the "strike zone area $A$"? Is this referring to a small area on the surface of the container?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan when one calculates the mean free time. (1)One usually assumes a spherical model for the molecule.(3) The strike zone is the face of cylinder as shown in the image (2) Yes it is an ideal gas